# MetaData API and Tooling API

Tags: apex, api, metadata-api, callout, tooling-api

Is it possible to get below things using **Apex**:

1. I want to get field Updates that are used in a particular or all WorkFlow rule/s.
2. I want to get Workflow rules and approval Processes that are associated with a single WorkflowFieldUpdate.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible. You can access Workflow Rule metadata through the Metadata API. There is an [Apex wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) available, and its README and [examples class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls) include some examples that can be adapted to get started on your objectives.

To read out Workflow Rule metadata, for example, you can do

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery> queries = new List<MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery>();        
MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryWorkflow = new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
queryWorkflow.type_x = 'WorkflowRule';
queries.add(queryWorkflow);     
MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, 25);
for(MetadataService.FileProperties fileProperty : fileProperties) {
            MetadataService.WorkflowRule wfr =
            (MetadataService.WorkflowRule) service.readMetadata('WorkflowRule',
new String[] { fileProperty.fullName }).getRecords()[0];
            System.debug(wfr);
}
```

That's not very efficient but it'll output each Workflow Rule's XML metadata into your logs, and you can examine it as an aid to understanding the (quite complex) metadata.

To implement your actual requirements, you'll want to extract your Workflow Rules along the lines above and examine their properties. You can find a reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_workflow.htm#!), in the Metadata API reference. The `actions` property includes a list of `WorkflowActionReference` items you can inspect, looking for the `type_x` property to be `FieldUpdate`.

For Approval Processes, a similar sequence of operations would obtain. See [`ApprovalProcess`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_approvalprocess.htm) in the Metadata API documentation for more, but you'd be looking at its several properties (`finalApprovalActions` and so on) that have the type `ApprovalAction`. That type has only one property, `action`, which is a list of `WorkflowActionReference` just like with Workflow Rules. You should be able to write the logic to correlate that data.

The Tooling API's [`WorkflowRule`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowrule.htm) support is layered on top of the Metadata API's. You could certainly go that route but you'll have to do some of the additional work to walk through the very complex response body that is handled by the `apex-mdapi` wrapper for you.